# How do I display formatted source-code comments?

Tags: ios, swift, comments

How do I display the formatted (markup) source-code comments?

I tried option-clicking on the following function name.  
And I don't see any change in the 'Quick Help' in the right-side menu.

The following code snippet shows some comment lines that I want to be able to display in its intended format; either as a popup or under the 'Quick Help' panel.

I tried various formatted texts and via template without success.

```
/// Converts an image buffer to a `UIImage`.
  ///
  /// @param imageBuffer The image buffer which should be converted.
  /// @param orientation The orientation already applied to the image.
  /// @return A new `UIImage` instance.
  public static func createUIImage(
    from imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer,
    orientation: UIImage.Orientation
  ) -> UIImage? {
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: Constantss.originalScale, orientation: orientation)
  }
```

Comment: Those don't look like legal code comment tags to me.

Comment: It's not my code; hence I couldn't launch the doc.  I'm able to get the comment working via a virgin code with proper format.

Comment: If the code comments are mis-formatted then you won't be able to see the inline documentation.  (I would expect you to see the summary comments but not the parameters and result)